# All properties are set to last loop iteration value [why?]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

Sample code:

```
var functions = {
 testFunction: function(){
  console.log('test');
 }      
};
var functionsClones = [];
for(i in [1,2,3]){
 var functionsClone = $.extend({}, functions);
 functionsClone.testFunction.i = i;
 functionsClones.push(functionsClone);
}
```

**$.extend** is jQuery function which allows to clone object instead of reffering to it.

Now let's print set properties:

```
$.each(functionsClones, function(key, functionsClone){
 console.log(functionsClone.testFunction.i);
});
```

It outputs 3 times '2' instead of 0, 1, 2. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` for iterating through arrays.

Comment: this sample code was quickly written just for example to demonstrate problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're setting `i` on the same `testFunction` object *(which happens to be a function)*. You're not creating a new function in each iteration of the loop.

Therefore, at the end of the loop, the function `testFunction` object holds the last value it received.

Because JavaScript only gives you reference to objects, and not the objects themselves, a copy isn't made.

To make a separate copy, you'd need to create the function in the loop.

Comment: so how to 'clone' function?

Comment: You'll need to create the function in the loop. But why do you want to put a property on the function in the first place? Why not put the property directly on the `functionsClone` object?

Comment: It's complicated, I need to maintain compatibility with one library's API and have to find some compromise :) Any ideas how to clone function, not creating it in the loop?

Comment: @MateuszMazurek: That's difficult, because you need to take into account variable scope. It can be sort of cloned, but any scoped variables will be lost. Is there some reason you don't just create a function in the loop that invokes the one you want to clone?